# How to create a Chart Annotation that covers the y-axis for the Shinobi iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

I would like to create a Chart Annotation that covers the y-axis like is shown in the image below.  The view containing "160.86" is the one I'm trying to mimic. Is this possible with SChartAnnotations provided by Shinobi?

Currently the annotation I'm using gets hidden behind the y-axis labels as it nears the edge of the chart plot area.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your annotation is getting hidden is because one of its superviews has `clipsToBounds` set to `YES`. To override this behaviour add the following:

```
myChart.canvas.glView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Note that you'll need to import the `SChartCanvas` header file:

```
#import <ShinobiCharts/SChartCanvas.h>
```

There is more info on this on the ShinobiControls forums at http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2013/5/shinobichart-clips-annotation-views